# Работа с whar_t и ifstream, нужна помощь по ошибке C++

Tags: c++

```
ifstream fin("C:\\UpdateStatus.system");
fin >> a;
wchar_t* url;
fin >> url;
fin.close();
if(a > b)
{
    cout << "DAEGERInjectorLog:Найдено новое обновление, скачать ? Если вы хотите скачать нажмите 'Да', если хотите продолжить без обновления нажмите 'Нет'";
    if (MessageBox(NULL, "Скачать новое обновление ?", "DAEGERInjector", MB_YESNO | MB_ICONQUESTION) == IDYES)
    {
        URLDownloadToFileW(0, url, L"C:\\UpdateStatus.system", 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Вот код, выдает 2 ошибки:

1. бинарный ">>": не найден оператор, принимающий правый операнд типа
   "wchar_t *" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)
2. отсутствует оператор ">>", соответствующий этим операндам

Мне нужно считать из txt файла строку ссылкой и записать ее в переменную `wchar_t* url`, что бы потом, по этой ссылке при выполненном условии, скачать файл в нужную директорию, но у меня никак не получается это сделать...

Comment: Необходимо работать с файлом в бинарном режиме.

Comment: @VTT, какой-то сомнительный совет...

Comment: 1. Не определено, что такое a и b, а догадаться сложно... 2. Хорошо бы пример содержимого файла.  3. Чтение "в указатель" не работает, надо явно выделить буфер, куда пойдет чтение. 4. Попробуйте wifstream, как советуют.

Comment: 4. ~~Попробуйте wifstream, как советуют~~ а тут был неправ, кажется из 2-байтовой кодировки только бинарным способом можно читать..

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> ifstream fin("C:\\UpdateStatus.system");
> ```

```
wifstream fin("C:\\UpdateStatus.system");
```

Comment: Вот это как раз сомнительный совет. `wifstream` все равно работает с байтами, не говоря уж о том, что после простой замены код в вопросе все равно останется нерабочим.

Comment: @VTT, в смысле? Чтение в неинициализированный указатель `url`, переменная `a` вообще неизвестно какого типа? Ну это уже к вопросу не относится.

Comment: В прямом смысле замена: `ifstream` на `wifstream` совершенно бесполезна. А для чтения wchar_t необходимо использовать бинарный режим

Comment: @VTT, обоснуй. Желательно в ответе.

Comment: Раньше можно было посредством https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf16 , но теперь их убрали. А без codecvt wifstream не может читать wchar_t и единственный вариант - работать с файлом в бинарном режиме и читать все используя простой read.

Comment: @VTT, так в wifstream есть openmode, так же можно использовать бинарный режим. Или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: @B1aZe разумеется можно

Comment: @VTT не убрали, а объявили устаревшим. Лет через 12, может, и уберут, а пока это - стандартный С++.